# Error restarting Zeppelin interpreters and saving their parameters

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have Zeppelin 0.7.2 installed and connected to Spark 2.1.1 standalone cluster.

It has been running fine for quite a while until I changed the Spark workers' settings, to double the workers' cores and executor memory. I also tried to change the parameters `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS` and `ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS` on zeppelin-env.sh, to make it request for more "Memory per node" on the Spark workers but it always requests only 1GB per node so I removed them.

I had an issue while developing a paragraph so I tried set `zeppelin.spark.printREPLOutput` to `true` on the web interface. But when I tried to save that setting, I only got a small transparent red box at right side of my browser window. So it fails to save that setting. I also got that small red box when I tried to restart the Spark interpreter. The same actually happens when I tried to change the parameters of all other interpreters or restart them.

There is nothing on the log files. So I am quite puzzled on this issue. Do any of you has ever experienced this issue? If so, what kind of solutions that you applied to fix it? If not, do you have any suggestions on how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for the noise. The issue was actually due to my silly mistake.

I actually have Zeppelin behind nginx. I recently played around with a new CMS. I didn't separate the configuration of the CMS and the proxy to Zeppelin. So any access to location containing `/api/`, like restarting Zeppelin interpreters or saving the interpreters' settings, got blocked. Separating the site configuration of the CMS and the proxy to Zeppelin on nginx solves the problem.